# How to properly override beans with Spring in Maven Projects with multiple modules based on runtime profiles?

Tags: java, spring, maven

So let's say I have a bean in `application-context.xml`:

```
<bean id="foo" class="biz.tugay.FooImpl" />
```

and I have another module, let's say module **thud** and in `application-context-thud.xml` I will also have:

```
<bean id="foo" class="biz.tugay.thud.ThudFooImpl" />
```

So when I run my application with profile thud activated, bean foo will be overriden with `biz.tugay.thud.FooImpl`. Up to this point all is ok.

But lets say all I want is something like this:

```
package biz.tugay

class FooImpl{
    void foo(){// Lots of code here};
}
```

and in the overriden bean all I want to do is:

```
package biz.tugay.thud

class ThudFooImpl{
    void foo(){
        if(something..) return;
        else {
            // Lots of code here
        }
    };
}
```

so what I currently do is this:

```
package biz.tugay.thud

import biz.tugay.FooImpl

class ThudFooImpl extends FooImpl{
    void foo(){
        if(something..) return;
        else {
            super.foo();
        }
    };
}
```

But the problem is, if `FooImpl` has dependencies, I will have to inject the dependencies to the `ThudFooImpl` as well. But as you can see from the code, I do not even need those dependencies in `ThudFooImpl`.. All I have is a simple if check.

So code will look like this in the xml files:

```
 <bean id="foo" class="biz.tugay.Foo">
    <constructor-arg ref="waldo"/>
    <property name="baz" ref="baz"/>
    <property name="qux" ref="qux"/>
    <property name="quux" ref="quux"/>
    <property name="corge" ref="corge"/>
</bean>

<bean id="foo" class="biz.tugay.thud.ThudFooImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="waldo"/>
    <property name="baz" ref="baz"/>
    <property name="qux" ref="qux"/>
    <property name="quux" ref="quux"/>
    <property name="corge" ref="corge"/>
</bean>
```

which looks like I am doing something wrong here?

Is there any way to override beans without requiring to inject all the dependencies to the subclassing bean?

Comment: If you're on Spring 3.1+ you should consider using Spring Profiles instead of Maven's - they're much better suited for a use case like this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I remember using it myself in practice, but I *think* it might be the `parent` attribute that you're looking for:

[Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions)
[Mkyong tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-configuration-inheritance/)

An un-tested example using your terms:

```
<bean id="foo" class="biz.tugay.Foo">
  <constructor-arg ref="waldo"/>
  <property name="baz" ref="baz"/>
  <property name="qux" ref="qux"/>
  <property name="quux" ref="quux"/>
  <property name="corge" ref="corge"/>
</bean>

<bean id="thudFoo" class="biz.tugay.thud.ThudFooImpl" parent="foo"/>
```

I expect this won't work exactly, I don't have a project to easily test it with, but hopefully together with the docs it will get you some of the way...

Answer (score 0):

You could make `ThusFooImpl` extend `FooImpl` by composition rather than inheritance.
They should both implement a `Foo` interface, and you could inject an instance of `FooImpl` into `ThudFooImpl`. Then call the injected `FooImpl` from the 2nd branch of your `if` statement in `ThudFooImpl`.